# I get an error when trying to centre my image in a canvas

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to centre my image in a canvas but i get this error.
`IndexError: tuple index out of range`
All help us appreciated :)
Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import*

main = Tk()
main.config(bg="grey66")
main.minsize(650,450)
main.maxsize(650,450)

mainFrameHigh = Frame(main)
mainFrameHigh.grid(row=0,column=0)

mainFrameHighP = Frame(mainFrameHigh)
mainFrameHighP.grid(row=0,column=0)

canvasHigh = Canvas(mainFrameHighP,width=225,height=225)
canvasHigh.grid(row=0,column=0)
highway = PhotoImage(file = "/home/olijrhodes/tkinter/LSPD/LSPD_Photos/highway.png")
canvasHigh.create_image(anchor=CENTER,image=highway)

main.mainloop()
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible for the code  you posted to give that error. You aren't referencing a tuple anywhere. Please provide the full error traceback and a proper [mcve].

Comment: You didn't provide x and y to `canvasHigh.create_image()`.

Comment: I've edited the post to include all of my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you need to pass the position arguments:

```
canvasHigh.create_image(anchor=CENTER,image=highway)
```

Also refer the [document](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm):

> anchor=
>
> Where to place the image relative to the given position. Default is CENTER.

So maybe you need:

```
canvasHigh.create_image(225/2, 225/2, image=highway) # width/2 and height/2
```